# Snap permissions problems

Tags: snap, spotify

I have been pulling my hair out with snap permissions issues. The apps that are specifically giving me the most trouble are Spotify (Premium Account) and bcompare (Beyond Compare). I'm runnning Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

The problem is that snap can't seem to access directories that I need it to.

Spotify, I would like it to access the audio files on an external hard drive that is mounted on /media for all users. The problem it gives me a "Could nor read the contents of "FOLDER" Error opening directory "FOLDER":Permission Denied for folders outside of its snap folder or my home directory.

It also won't follow a symlink to the drive. I presume it must be operating as a different user since my user has access to all drives and directories.

bcompare (Beyond Compare) has the same issue. The whole purpose of bcompare is to compare one directory to another to see if you have missing or duplicate files, but now that it's a snap, the only way I can get it to compare directories on external drives is to change the fstabs of the drives to mount inside the bcompare snap folder, and reboot the computer.

This caused tremendous problems since it changes the directory location, which then messes up syncing to Dropbox and Google Drive-which then start deleting files in the cloud since the directory no longer exists and it takes about a month to resync when I revert the fstab back to the original.

Is there a way to give snap access to the external drives, or run snaps as my user, or add snap to my group, or some way to have snaps access directories outside of their snap folder?